# Jquery loading Webpages

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I load external Website or Webpages into a DIV tag without using Jquery load(); function, since load() function is using AJAX. but apart from that is there any other simple way to loading Webpages

Comment: As your question seems to be more about *not* using jQuery, I added the javascript tag.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear in fact. Can you confirm your goal is to load a page into a div *without* using jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, jQuery is just a helper for basic javascript functions.

You may use this :

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open('GET', url);
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById('idOfTheDiv').innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
    }
}
httpRequest.send();
```

This supposes you have a div with id `idOfTheDiv` :

```
<div id=idOfTheDiv></div>
```